# JQuery form validation does not work for me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I have tested this code in http://jsfiddle.net/gLpHY/92/, in there it runs fine but when I run it in my computer it does not work. (I have tested two versions of this code once using just html and jquery and the next time I use them with php, both of them did not work for me.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/tableCss.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="<?php echo base_url()?>js/projs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frm"><?php $a=array("id"=>"myForm","name"=>"myForm");
echo form_open('site/search',$a); ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo form_label('Question:','question'); ?>
            <?php echo form_input('question', set_value('question', @$_GET['question']), 'id="question"', 'name="question"'); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo form_label('Category:','category'); ?>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('category', $category_options, set_value('category', @$_GET['category']), 'id="category"', 'name="category"'); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo form_label('Score:','score'); ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('score_comparison', array('gt' => '>', 'gte' =>'>=' , 'eq' => '=', 'lt' => '<', 'lte' => '<='), set_value('score_comparison', @$_GET['score_comparison']), 'id="score_comparison"', 'name="score_comparison"'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input('score', set_value('score', @$_GET['score']), 'id="score"', 'name="score"'; ?>
         </div>
         <div>
             <?php echo form_submit('action','');?>
         </div>
         <?php echo form_close();?>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                question: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: { 
                question:{
                    required: "Please enter some text" 
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please remove the extra tilde from the code part! it can't be read.

Comment: thank you, I have edited it

Comment: I think you're missing an opening `<script>` tag before that function at the end

Comment: tanx, no just I forgot to paste it here but in the actual code I wrote it, still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, replace you `<?php echo base_url()?>` with just `/`. You can use relative path for resources from your site. Path should be like this: `scr="/js/jquery-1.12.0.js"` for all you scripts.

For second replace your string `$().ready(function () {` with `$(function () {`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion unfortunately, still it is not working

Comment: Thank you now it works well, it was an error on link in src :)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in the full URL instead of using `<?php echo base_url()?>` as I have seen that cause problems with printing the URL twice and then the page obviously not being able to find it. Also, the way you have written .ready() is not recommended. You might want to consider adding document inside the parenthesis like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

[.ready() source](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the code as your suggestions:<script type="text/javascript" scr="http://localhost/myproject/js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://localhost/myproject/js/projs.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://localhost/myproject/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> and $(document).ready(function () { but still it is not working :(